# What is the best way to manage feature milestones and sprints with Github?

Tags: github

Github provides nice feature to manage feature completeness OR sprint completeness. It's called `Milestones` and it's really nice.

However, sometimes we need to track both completeness of the feature (e.g. "Refactoring payment systems integration") and completeness of the sprint (e.g. "Sprint week 15").

Is there any way to do so using Github issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub does not currently allow you to assign multiple milestones to an issue. There is an [issue tracking this feature request](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/441), but there seems to be little movement on it.

There's a couple of workarounds possible. The simplest one is to use Milestones to track sprints, and labels to track features. While labels do not give you the nice "X% completed" overview that Milestones do, you *can* quickly (single click) get an overview of all issues tagged with a label, and see how many are open vs. closed.

Another possibility is that you use  Task Lists (see [GitHub Markdown guide](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/)) to your advantage. Instead of having each issue belonging to a particular feature as an independent GitHub issue, you track the entire feature as a single issue, and add a Task List to the issue to track individual items. The advantage of this is that you get a nice progress bar in your issue overview, showing you feature completeness. A disadvantage is that you cannot assign individual tasks to separate developers any longer.

Comment: thanks. Looks like I have to go with labels, despite it feels weird to use them for tracking feature completeness. In my case something like EPIC issue looks more natural. Hope, github team will implement this feature soon.